# Rails button_to with image and actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show button with image. 
I have this code

```
<%= image_submit_tag "down.png", controller: "posts", action: "votedown", post_id: post.id, topic_id: post.topic_id, class: "xta" %>
```

Its visible properly but not calling action "votedown"

In my routes I have

```
post '/votedown', to: 'posts#votedown
```

Please also suggest if there is any other way to call the method votedown with params and image "down.png"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`image_submit_tag` must be used in conjunction with a form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag) - it works just a normal html `<input type="submit">` button.

You might also want to change your route definition into something more restful:

```
patch '/posts/:id/votedown' => "posts#votedown", as: 'votedown_post'
```

This makes it more apparent that this route acts on a post - and we use the `PATCH` method since we are changing a resource instead of creating a new resource.

Armed with our new route we can simply create a form:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: votedown_post_path(@post) ) do |f| %>
  <%= image_submit_tag "down.png", class: "xta" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that you do not need to add an input for the post id since it will be available as `params[:id]`.

Another way to do this would be to use [Rails unobstructive javascript](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) driver to create a link or button which sends a `PATCH` request to `'/posts/:id/votedown'`.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("down.png", class: "xta"), votedown_post_path(@post), method: :patch %>
```

Comment: I have to submit 2 params to votedown method post id and topic id above code is submit only post id

Comment: If you rewrite the route as I have suggested you can get the post id from `params[:id]`. Also you should not need to pass `topic_id` unless post is a resource which is nested in topic. In that case you would want your route to read `/topics/:topic_id/posts/:id`.  If you insist on doing it wrong you would add the fields to the form.